# What do I call a number that has a period in it?

Tags: single-word-requests

My brain is standing completely still on this. I'm sure I've known this in the past. The difference between the number:

```
123
```

and

```
123.25
```

is obviously that the first number number is a "full" number. There is no fraction of a number that requires that the number be written with a period symbol and more numbers describing the fraction.

What is a number *called* when it can be written without a period, and what is it called otherwise? Also, what are the numbers behind the period symbol called? (So really this is a request for three words, not one. I hope that flies.)

Comment: You also need a fourth term to describe **123.** -- a number which has a decimal part but has been rounded to the nearest integer value. You might also want to distinguish **123.000**.

Comment: "*Whole number*": **A number without fractions; an integer**; and "*Fraction*": **A numerical quantity that is not a whole number**. Don't split hairs. HTH

Comment: I think it depends on the context a bit too, in computer science `123.` is usually a _very_ different number from `123`

Comment: @wim: The main reason for me asking this question was actually a comment I was writing in a Python source file, where I was trying to explain that if the input `float` variable was *"round"*, it would be converted to an integer.

Comment: @codemonkey Just with the new context, you could just be explicit in this case with something like **if the input float variable is a whole number (i.e. there's nothing after the decimal point) it'll be converted to an int** to avoid any confusion? And mild curiosity, can I get a pointer at the source? Am just wondering how it's implemented :)

Comment: @tanantish: [tabulardata.py](http://pastebin.com/sZUUEJwx) - See line 480. :-)

Comment: It is a common phrase in Computer Science -- numbers without a period symbol is called "integer" and the other one is called "decimal" or "floating point number".

Comment: @shuangwhywhy: Of course, but what do you call a floating point number that is completely round, so that it can be converted to an integer without losing any information?

Comment: @Codemonkey I can't think off my head. So what is your comment?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. **Counting numbers** = {1, 2, 3, ...}
2. **Whole numbers** = {0, 1, 2, 3, ...}
3. **Natural numbers** is often synonymous with *counting numbers*. But the term is sometimes used to mean *whole numbers*.
4. **Integers** = {..., -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...}
5. *½* is an example of a **fraction**. *1½* is an example of a **mixed number** and specifically a **mixed fraction**.
6. *123.25* is also an example of a **mixed number**, specifically a **mixed decimal**, and usually just called a **decimal number** or simply a **decimal**.
7. *123.25* is also an example of a **rational number**. It can be written as a *ratio* (hence, rational) of two integers. Both *½* and *⅓* (which has a repeating decimal) are rational for the same reason.
8. π (pi, 3.1415...) (which has an infinite, non-repeating decimal part) is an example of an **irrational number**. It *cannot* be written as a ratio of two integers. While the fraction 22/7 is often used to do so, it is only an approximate representation.
9. **Real numbers** comprise both rational and irrational numbers.
10. **Imaginary numbers** are those numbers which are not *real*. **Complex numbers** are those that have both *real* and *imaginary* components. Consequently, all numbers, real or imaginary, can be represented as complex numbers.

The part before the decimal point is a numbers **integral** (or integer) part and after it is its **decimal** part. In terms of mathematical terminology, the before and after parts are sometimes referred to as the [characteristic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/characteristic) and [mantissa](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mantissa) respectively. As Wiktionary states, these two terms are often required when working with logarithms.

Comment: What about a mixed number with an infinite *repeating* decimal part? Would that still be a rational number?

Comment: @Codemonkey I've updated my answer to address this. But, in short, yes.

Comment: π is irrational, but more commonly is called transcendental because it is not an [algebraic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number).  Square roots of integers are algebraic, and if not integral are irrational.  Also, item 10 is incorrect.  The real numbers are a subset of the [complex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number); every real is a complex number with its imaginary part being zero.

Comment: @jwpat7 Re: complex numbers, good point. I've edited the answer to address this. Please check.

Comment: “Imaginary numbers are those numbers which are not real” is incorrect.  Imaginary numbers are complex numbers whose real part is zero.  Complex numbers with nonzero imaginary and nonzero real parts are neither purely imaginary nor real.  In the usual Cartesian-coordinates visualization of complex numbers, *reals* are those complex numbers that lie on the x-axis, and *imaginaries* are those complex numbers that lie on the y-axis.  BTW, if complex numbers are relevant here, surely you should go ahead and explain how they fit into [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion).

Comment: @jwpat7 I disagree. _i_ is purely _imaginary_. It can be represented as a _complex number_, _0 + 1i_. 2 is purely real and can also be represented as a complex number, _2 + 0i_.

Comment: Yes, of course *i =  0 + 1i* and *2 = 2 + 0i*, both are complex numbers, *i* is  pure imaginary, 2 is real, fully in agreement with my comments about reals being complex with zero imaginary part, imaginary being complex with zero real part.  What do you disagree with?  Ref: [Imaginary numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_numbers) says “Imaginary numbers can therefore be thought of as complex numbers whose real part is zero.”

Comment: @jwpat7 I disagree with your statement that “Imaginary numbers are those numbers which are not real” is incorrect. _i_ is an imaginary number, yes?

Comment: Of course *i* is an imaginary number.  The error in “Imaginary numbers are those numbers which are not real” is demonstrated by *1+i* which is not real and also not imaginary.  It is a complex number that is neither real nor imaginary.  Certainly imaginaries are not real, but not all not-reals are imaginary.

Comment: "Complex numbers are those that have both real and imaginary components" - false: 42 is a complex number. It's also a natural number, but natural numbers are a subset of complex numbers. Better: "Complex numbers are those that have either real or imaginary components, or both".

Comment: @Konerak: So to summarize, all numbers are complex numbers?

Comment: Hubro: it's about sets. Every "whole number" is also an integer, since the set of whole numbers is a subset of the set of integers. Every integer is also a complex number, since the set of complex numbers consists of two sets: real numbers & imaginary numbers. A drawing might help here. So, all numbers mentioned here above are indeed complex numbers, but people have created bigger sets than complex numbers (eg Quaternions).

Answer (score 7):

The first one is called a natural number (if it's positive) or an integer (if it's either positive or negative), the other one is often called a rational number (if the decimal string terminates or repeats in a pattern) or a real number (if there is no restriction on how long or regular the decimal string is). To the left of the decimal is the integer part and to the right of the decimal is the fractional part.

Comment: You could also call the first one a *whole number*, generally a synonym for *integer*.

Comment: Would it be wrong to call the first number a *round* number? That sounds right to me.

Comment: @Codemonkey *round* number would not be wrong and will be understood. it would depend on the audience whether it's more appropriate than *integer*.

Comment: @Codemonkey If you're not talking [mathematical definitions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RoundNumber.html) then I'd say avoid 'round number' as it's a bit of a fluid term more closely related to the degree of precision. For example if something is expected to be in the range 0-99 with a fractional part, it sounds natural. If you move into another context such as forex trading (there's whole strategies on round number forex trading), it'd mean roughly numbers zeroing the last two sig figs, not all fractional components.

Comment: @tanantish: I'm looking for words that the layman will understand. I'm comfortable with using "round number" for an integer, but what would be a common, not necessarily *technically* correct, word for a number that is not an integer? A word you would use in a casual conversation?

Comment: @Codemonkey the first comment suggests *whole number*, which is the word they teach you in grade school, so that will be best for the layman. I hadn't even realized there was a technical sense of *round number* until @ tanantish pointed it out.

Comment: @codemonkey Hmm.. the best I can come up with would be 'decimal number' and 'whole number'. Not ideal, but should work in general conversation (and not invoke any of the scarier real/irrational conversations)

Answer (score 4):

[mixed decimal](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&tbo=u&q=mixed+decimal&tbs=dfn:1&sa=X&ei=FsT4UJz_Me_L0AXdqoGYAQ&ved=0CC8QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=4588547da649677a&biw=1149&bih=864) *- a combination of a whole number and decimal, such as 59.8, 810.85*

For some, that's as opposed to a [decimal fraction](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/decimal+fraction), defined there by thefreedictionary as *a decimal having no digits to the left of the decimal point except zero, such as 0.2 or 0.00354*

Others, such as [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decimal%20fraction) (and me!) define a **decimal fraction** as

> a fraction (as .25 = 25⁄100 or .025 = 25⁄1000) *or mixed number* (as 3.025 = 325⁄1000) in which the denominator is a power of 10 usually expressed by use of the decimal point. *[italics mine]*

Answer (score 2):

A number with no decimal values is called an *integer.*

If there are a limited number of decimal digits or it contains an infinite set of repeating digits, it is a *rational number*.
If there are an infinite amount of decimal digits, it is an *irrational number*.
The set of rational and irrational numbers are *real numbers.*

If there is a decimal point, the numbers to the left are the *integer part* and the numbers to the right are called the *fractional part*.

Comment: Do you claim that 0.112211122211112222..., with its  infinite sets of repeating digits, is a rational number?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal#Converting_repeating_decimals_to_fractions

Repeating decimals can be converted to fractions as shown above.

Comment: Merely referring to "repeating decimals" is too simple-minded.  For example, numbers with repeating patterns like 0.01011011101111011111... are irrational.  You need to include the word *periodic* or *cyclic* in the definition.  See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal) article.

Comment: Exactly, see wikipedia article. They are called repeating decimals, not periodic decimals or cyclic decimals. Your examples do not repeat.